# How to add a 3D object into local Google Earth plugin?

Tags: javascript, kml, google-earth, google-earth-plugin, kmz

As I understand there is no [opportunity](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/3dwh/epXUQA2bJ2s/pw7G8E6wtZ4J) to add 3D object into the Google Earth, therefore the instrument yet provide chance to add objects in local GE (?). And what is exactly what we are looking for. We tried to do some examples from [official page](https://kml-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/interactive/index.html#./Models/Models.Macky_Auditorium_%28ResourceMap%29.kml) without success in adding exactly 3D object and placed it in required coordinates. And my questions are:

1. Is it enough to have GE plugin to have a local version of GE or what exactly we need?
2. Is it really possible to add 3D object to GE local plugin?
3. How to run this example with required coordinates (approximately *long*: 51.02  *lat*:71.08)?
4. If it's necessary to add .dae file, how to change their location coordinates?

---

Here is our full html file with JS script ([kmz-file](http://www.google.kz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDMQFjAB&url=http://www.docmercury.com/ge/wp-content/uploads/kmz/The%2520Pentagon.kmz&ei=iHUmU9KlLuvoywPe7oD4Dg&usg=AFQjCNFxeNsqkjVmJ0FoYZVRg1mzpVa01A&bvm=bv.62922401,d.bGQ)):

```
<!--
You are free to copy and use this sample in accordance with the terms of the
Apache license (http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html)
-->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Google Earth API Sample</title>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var ge;

    google.load("earth", "1");

    function init() {
      google.earth.createInstance('map3d', initCallback, failureCallback);
    }

    function initCallback(pluginInstance) {
      ge = pluginInstance;
      ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);

      // add a navigation control
      ge.getNavigationControl().setVisibility(ge.VISIBILITY_AUTO);

      // add some layers
      ge.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById(ge.LAYER_BORDERS, true);
      ge.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById(ge.LAYER_ROADS, true);

      // just for debugging purposes
      document.getElementById('installed-plugin-version').innerHTML =
        ge.getPluginVersion().toString();

    var href = 'The_Pentagon.kmz';
    //var href = 'http://localhost/Users/k.bazaraly/Desktop/GoogleEarthTest/kml_example.kml';
    google.earth.fetchKml(ge, href, function(kmlObject) {
        if (kmlObject)
            ge.getFeatures().appendChild(kmlObject);
        if (kmlObject.getAbstractView() !== null)
            ge.getView().setAbstractView(kmlObject.getAbstractView());
    }); 

    }

    function failureCallback(errorCode) {
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="init()" style="font-family: arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; border: 0;">
    <div id="map3d" style="width: 500px; height: 380px;"></div>
    <br>
    <div>Installed Plugin Version: <span id="installed-plugin-version" style="font-weight: bold;">Loading...</span></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this demo instead
https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#creating_3d_models

It uses the current viewpoint to place the model with this bit of code

```
var la = ge.getView().copyAsLookAt(ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);
loc.setLatitude(la.getLatitude());
loc.setLongitude(la.getLongitude());
```

remove first line and change next two to

```
loc.setLatitude(71.08);
loc.setLongitude(51.02);
```